# SSRS Sql Server Reporting Server Custom Security 2019 exception in Windows Server 2019

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I am facing problem with respect to SSRS(Sql Server Reporting Server)  2019 Custom security Exception in windows server 2019,

Getting error as sqlAuthCookie is null, sending WebRequest to Reportserver to generate sqlAuthCookie from VB.net code but server unable to generate Cookie.

Anything solution/help would be much appreciated

Tried sending request from Vb.net to SSRS windows server 2019

Getting Custom security exception error and sqlAuthCookie error also

```
VB.NET Code

Protected Overrides Function GetWebResponse(ByVal request As WebRequest) As WebResponse
        Dim response As WebResponse = MyBase.GetWebResponse(request)
        Dim cookieName As String = response.Headers("RSAuthenticationHeader")
        ' If the response contains an auth header, store the cookie
        If Not (cookieName Is Nothing) Then
            Dim webResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(response, HttpWebResponse)
            Dim authCookie As Cookie = webResponse.Cookies(cookieName)
            ' If the auth cookie is null, throw an exception
            If authCookie Is Nothing Then
                Throw New Exception("Unable to generate report - the Reporting Services Custom Security Extension is expected to be enabled in XB")
            End If
            ' otherwise save it for this request
            Me.AuthCookie = authCookie
            ' and send it to the client
        End If
        Return response
End Function
```

```
SSRS service code
//adding new GetUserInfo method for IAuthenticationExtension2
       public void GetUserInfo(IRSRequestContext requestContext, out IIdentity userIdentity, out IntPtr userId)
       {
           userIdentity = null;
           if (requestContext.User != null)
           {
               userIdentity = requestContext.User;
           }

           // initialize a pointer to the current user id to zero
           userId = IntPtr.Zero;
       }
```

Comment: If this is actually a coding problem, might be worth posting the relevant code.  If this is more or a server config issue, maybe  https://serverfault.com/ or https://superuser.com/ might be more appropriate.   At a reach, the fact you are specifically mentioned server2019, does that mean it's worked in other environments?

Comment: Hi, yes it is working fine in previous version of SQL Server (2016, 2014 and 2012)

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for your answer, also bringing to your notice that, already installed custom security exception, unfortunately still authentication error persisting.

For more clarity on the problem statement, here by requesting to go through another forum link which I had created.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1180046/ssrs-reporting-server-2019-customsecurity-extensio

Thanks for your support.